# neo4j vs orientdb, which is best for storing hierarchial data?

Tags: neo4j, orientdb

neo4j vs orientdb, which is best for storing hierarchial data?

Answer (score -1):

You can see this http://orientdb.com/orientdb-vs-neo4j/.
Hope it helps.